# proving the equality of two sigma

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to prove that these two sigma are equal, but I can't find a way
$${\rm 1+}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -4}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -2}{\rm )n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$
$${\rm =-}{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm n+1}}}{\rm +}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -2}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -2}{\rm )n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$
(n is an even positive integer)

Edit: for n=2 the left side is
$${\rm 1+}{{{\rm (-1)}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm 5}}\over{{\rm 2!}}}{\rm +}{{{\rm (-1)}^{{\rm 2}}{\rm \times}{\rm 2}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm 5}{\rm \times}{\rm 7}}\over{{\rm 4!}}}{\rm =1-10+}{{{\rm 35}}\over{{\rm 3}}}{\rm =}{{{\rm 8}}\over{{\rm 3}}}$$
and the right side is
$$-{{4}\over{3}}+{{(-1)^{2}\times 2\times 4}\over{2!}}=4-{{4}\over{3}}={{{\rm 8}}\over{{\rm 3}}}$$
Therefore, this proposition is true for n=2. Now suppose it is true for n, that is:
$${\rm 1+}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -4}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -2}{\rm )n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}{\rm =-}{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm n+1}}}{\rm +}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -2}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -2}{\rm )n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$
We prove that it is also true for n+2, that is:
$${\rm 1+}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n+4}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm (}{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -4}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm n}{\rm (}{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}{\rm (n}{\rm +4}{\rm )}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +5}{\rm )(n}{\rm +7}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}{\rm =-}{{{\rm n+4}}\over{{\rm n+3}}}{\rm +}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm (}{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -2}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm n(}{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 4}{\rm )}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +5}{\rm )(n}{\rm +7}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm (}{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$

Comment: Induction?  Note:  are you assuming that $n$ is even or are the summation limits missing a floor function?

Comment: @lulu n is even. Is it solved by induction? Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: I didn't try it, but it seems like the obvious approach.  Shifting from $n$ to $n+2$, most of the sums match, so you only have to look at a couple of stub terms.  Or at least that's the hope.